# run an .exe file in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, installation

A bit of a silly question , please forgive my lack though, new UNIX user .

I have an setup_test.exe file if there a way that i can make it "run-install" or compile it in UNIX based machine, or I need the source code to start with?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this executable came from the Windows environment, it won't run under UNIX/Linux without lots of help.

Two options:

1. If you have the source code and the application doesn't rely on a lot of Windows specific libraries, you could try compiling it in your current environment.
2. The WINE emulator can often run Windows executables, depending again on what libraries from Windows are used.

If it isn't a Windows exe and is native to your current environment, then ./exename.exe should work provided you have the permissions to execute it.

Comment: @user4010903 I believe it is a windows executable, thus WINE is the only option?
The machine I am using is a network connected machine that has WINE, but I do not know the libraries cause it is precompiled.
How can i load it in WINE, if possible ?